# Unable to fix python exception

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, proxy, python-requests-html

I have this finished python web scrapping script. Unfortunately, after some sometimes hours other times days of execution, I get the following errors. I really don’t know what’s causing the error and is so frustrating because every time I want to try a fix it takes a day to find out that it didn't work.

The script is making requests through 100 webshare proxies randomly.

I would really appreciate if any of you could tell me how to fix this.

```
ERROR 1 ->

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Scrapper/./run_15days.py", line 112, in <module>
    response = reqs.get(url,proxies={
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))

ERROR 2 ->

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 966, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Scrapper/./run_365days.py", line 111, in <module>
    response = reqs.get(url,proxies={
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

The code of the script is the following:

```
import requests
import json
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
import mariadb 
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename="Logs/log_14days_flights.txt", level=logging.DEBUG, filemode = "w+")
conn = mariadb.connect(
    user="",
    password="",
    host="localhost",
    database="")

z = 0

header = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" ,
        'referer':'https://www.google.com/'
        }
status_code = 403
while status_code == 403 or status_code == 404:
    reqs = requests.Session()
    response = reqs.get("https://website.com",proxies={
                            "http": "http://p.webshare.io:9999",
                            "https": "http://p.webshare.io:9999"
                        }, headers=header)
    z = z + 1
    print('Response HTTP Status Code: ', response.status_code)
    status_code = response.status_code

airprot_response = response.content
# print(response.content)
my_json = airprot_response.decode('utf8')
airport_data = json.loads(my_json)
print(type(airport_data))
# airport_data = json.dumps(airport_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
# print(type(airport_data))
airport_lst = airport_data.get('airports')

airport_codes_lst = []
for ai in airport_lst:
    airport_code = ai.get('iataCode')
    airport_codes_lst.append(airport_code)

print(len(airport_codes_lst))
# print(airport_codes_lst)
airport_number = 1
for i in airport_codes_lst:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = "create table if not exists {airport}(id INT primary key auto_increment,dep_airport VARCHAR(100),arrival_airport VARCHAR(100),flight_number VARCHAR(100),flight_key VARCHAR(100), dep_date VARCHAR(100),arrival_date VARCHAR(100),flight_duration VARCHAR(100), date_dep_ VARCHAR(100), updated_on timestamp);".format(airport=i)
    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    print('Airport No. : ', airport_number)
    logging.info("Program is working as expected")
    url = "https://www.website.com".format(airport = i) 
    print(url)
    status_code = 403
    while status_code == 403 or status_code == 404:
        reqs = requests.Session()
        response = reqs.get(url,proxies={
                                            "http": "http://p.webshare.io:9999",
                                            "https": "http://p.webshare.io:9999"
                                        }, headers=header)
        z = z + 1
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: ', response.status_code)
        status_code = response.status_code

    dest_airprot_response = response.content
    my_json = dest_airprot_response.decode('utf8')
    dest_airport_data = json.loads(my_json)
    # print(dest_airport_data)
    fares_data_lst = dest_airport_data.get('fares')
    dest_airport_lst = []
    for fares in fares_data_lst:
        outbound_data = fares.get('outbound')
        dest_airport = outbound_data.get('arrivalAirport').get('iataCode')
        dest_airport_lst.append(dest_airport)

    print(dest_airport_lst)
    
    for j in dest_airport_lst:
        url = "https://www.website.com".format(org = i, dst = j)
        print(url)
        status_code = 403
        while status_code == 403 or status_code == 404:
            reqs = requests.Session()
            response = reqs.get(url,proxies={
                                                "http": "http://p.webshare.io:9999",
                                                "https": "http://p.webshare.io:9999"
                                            }, headers=header)
            z = z + 1
            print('Response HTTP Status Code: ', response.status_code)
            status_code = response.status_code
        date_response = response.content
        my_json = date_response.decode('utf8')
        dates_data = json.loads(my_json)
        print(type(dates_data))
        days15_date = date.today() + timedelta(days=15)
        days15_date = days15_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        # print(type(days15_date))
        for dts in dates_data:
            # print(type(date))
            if dts >= days15_date:
                continue
            url = "https://www.website.com".format(dst = j, org = i, date = dts)
            print(url)
            status_code = 403
            while status_code == 403 or status_code == 404:
                reqs = requests.Session()
                response = reqs.get(url,proxies={
                                                    "http": "http://p.webshare.io:9999",
                                                    "https": "http://p.webshare.io:9999"
                                                }, headers=header)
                z = z + 1
                print('Response HTTP Status Code: ', response.status_code)
                status_code = response.status_code

            flight_response = response.content
            my_json = flight_response.decode('utf8')
            flight_data = json.loads(my_json)
            # print(flight_data)
            trip_lst = flight_data.get('trips')
            for trip in trip_lst:
                dates = trip.get('dates')
                for dt in dates:
                    flights = dt.get('flights')
            # print(flights)
            if len(flights)>= 1:
                for fl in flights:
                    flight_key = str(fl.get('flightKey'))
                    print(flight_key)
                    arrival_airport = str(fl.get('segments')[0].get("destination"))
                    print(arrival_airport)
                    dep_airport = str(fl.get('segments')[0].get("origin"))
                    print(dep_airport)
                    flight_number = str(fl.get('segments')[0].get("flightNumber"))
                    print(flight_number)
                    dep_date = str(fl.get('segments')[0].get("time")[0])
                    print(dep_date)
                    arrival_date = str(fl.get('segments')[0].get("time")[1])
                    print(arrival_date)
                    flight_duration = str(fl.get('segments')[0].get("duration"))
                    print(flight_duration)
                    date_dep_ = dep_date.split('T')[0]
                    print(date_dep_)
                    try:
                        cur = conn.cursor()
                        query = f"DELETE FROM " + i
                        query = query + " WHERE flight_number =" + '"' +flight_number+ '"' + "and date_dep_ =" + '"' +date_dep_+ '"'
                        print(query)
                        cur.execute(query)
                        print(f"{cur.rowcount} details deleted")
                        conn.commit()
                    except:
                        print("Nothing to Delete")
                    cur = conn.cursor()
                    query = f"INSERT INTO " + i
                    query = query + f" (flight_key, arrival_airport,dep_airport, flight_number, dep_date, arrival_date, flight_duration, date_dep_) VALUES ('{flight_key}', '{arrival_airport}', '{dep_airport}', '{flight_number}', '{dep_date}', '{arrival_date}', '{flight_duration}', '{date_dep_}')"
                    # cur.execute(
                    #         "INSERT INTO flight_data (flight_key,arrival_airport,dep_airport,flight_number,dep_date,arrival_date,flight_duration) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                    #         (flight_key,arrival_airport,dep_airport,flight_number,dep_date,arrival_date,flight_duration))
                    cur.execute(query)
                    print(f"{cur.rowcount} details inserted")
                    logging.info(f"{cur.rowcount} details inserted")
                    conn.commit()
            time.sleep(6)
        time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging_msg = i +" Airport flights Completed"
    logging.info(logging_msg)
    airport_number = airport_number + 1

print(z)
```

Thank you very much in advanced for all the help and time spent on helping me on this. I have been struggling with this for weeks and really cannot find a solution.

Comment: can you try to add "verify=False
" in your requests 
ex: requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)
I am seeing lot of SSL errors in log you shared

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the connection closed from the server side `Remote end closed connection without response`, which causes all those errors.

Would suggest implementing a retry strategy ([something like urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry), see example below), **if the case is really not about you spamming too much, or some scrape detection**.

```py
retries = Retry(connect=5, read=2, redirect=5)
http = PoolManager(retries=retries)
response = http.request("GET", "https://example.com/")
```

Or per request ([this is from the urllib3 documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry)):

```py
response = http.request("GET", "https://example.com/", retries=Retry(10))
```

If it is really due to them understanding that you are scraping, you need better mitigation techniques, slowing down scraping, more IP, etc.